# PHP Class attribute call constructor

Tags: php, class, constructor, attributes

I wrote the following example class:

```
class Test {
    public $baseSymbol;
    public $counterSymbol;
    public function __construct($baseSymbol,$counterSymbol) {
        $this->baseSymbol = $baseSymbol;
        $this->counterSymbol = $counterSymbol;
    }
    public static $var = new Test("CV", "SWR");
}
```

As you may noticed, I want that the attribute $var of the class Test become a Object of type Test. I did the same thing easily in Java, as a public static variable, but in PHP it's not working...Is there any alternative for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Does it specifically need to be an object

Comment: Yes @ArtisiticPhoenix , is that possible in PHP?

Comment: In a roundabout way.

Comment: You obviously cant create the class where the class variable is defined.  Consequence of run-time compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you cant set complex types within the definition of the class variables, the only way I can perceive doing this in PHP is to use the magic of procedural code ( Joke ).  Now It's important to note that within the file the class exists in you can certainly do something like this.

```
class Test {
    public $baseSymbol;
    public $counterSymbol;
    protected static $var;


    public function __construct($baseSymbol,$counterSymbol) {
        $this->baseSymbol = $baseSymbol;
        $this->counterSymbol = $counterSymbol;
    }

    public static setVar(Test $var ){
        self::$var = $var;
    }

}

Test::setVar( new Test() );
```

This is pretty standard fare, but as mentioned above by placing the setting code within the class, when the file is loaded the setting is done immediately and pre-loads the class instance before anything else can be done.

This is simply a consequence of not being pre-compiled.  When the class is loaded there is no guarantee that a complex object that is required is present, and because of that PHP plays it safe and restricts this ability.

I did change the variable to be `protected` to keep it encapsulated, this of course is optional.  I also added type casting which will insure that only an object or descendant object of `Test` is used as the input.

Probably not the most favorable solution but one that will work. One last thing you could do just to make sure if you really want to keep it from being changed is to change the setter like this.

```
    public static setVar(){
        if( !self::$var ){
           self::$var = new Test();
        }
    }
```

This way you just call the method with `Test::setVar()` and once it's got a value it always returns not false, so it will not be changed latter.

One last note, if you truly want a copy of the class itself, this is the Test class with a static instance of itself ( like a singleton ) then do this instead of using the name

```
   public static setVar(){
        if( !self::$var ){
           self::$var = new self;
        }
    }
```

Now to wrap that into a singleton, you can do the class like this.

```
final class Test {
    public $baseSymbol;
    public $counterSymbol;
    protected static $var;

    //no constuction
    private function __construct($baseSymbol,$counterSymbol) {
        $this->baseSymbol = $baseSymbol;
        $this->counterSymbol = $counterSymbol;
    }

    //no cloning
    private function __clone(){}

    public static getInstance(){
        if( !self::$var ){
          self::$var = new self('%', '#');
        }
        return self::$var
    }

}

$Test = Test::getInstance();
```

Here I go rambling, now ponder saving the instance in an array with a key. Then you can have a Multiton ( is that a thing? );

```
public static getInstance($type, $baseSymbol,$counterSymbol){
    if( !isset(self::$var[$type] )){
       self::$var[$type] = new self($baseSymbol, $counterSymbol);
    }
    return self::$var[$type];
}
```

It makes a great database class, just saying.

Answer (score 0):

You could access `$var` via a getter and initialize it there on demand:

```
private static $var;

public static function getVar() 
{
    if (null === self::$var) {
        self::$var = new Whatever();
    }

    return self::$var;
}
```